# How can I get top artist youtube data API v3

Tags: android, api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using Youtube API V3 to fetch top artist from youtube API for my Android app. I want to show Top Artists for each country. Any idea how can I retrieve the list of top Artists from Youtube API. located hear https://www.youtube.com/yt/artists/charts.html

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/yt/artists/charts.html

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible to get the artist list via youtube data api. Because the acceptable "type" values for search.list() does not have artist resource:

[Doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) say:

> Acceptable values are: channel, playlist, video

The only way I can think of is to scrap the data of that web page https://artists.youtube.com/charts/artists

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this but give it a try, use `Search:list` which returns a collection of search results that match the query parameters specified in the API request. By default, a search result set identifies matching [video](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos), [channel](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels), and [playlist](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists) resources, but you can also configure queries to only retrieve a specific type of resource. Include `regionCode` and `type` paramenter.

The **regionCode** parameter instructs the API to return search results for the specified country. The parameter value is an ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code.

The **type** parameter restricts a search query to only retrieve a particular type of resource. The value is a comma-separated list of resource types. The default value is video,channel,playlist.

Note: A call to this method has a quota cost of 100 units.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the **`YouTube Music Global Charts`** channel on YouTube - i.e: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCrKZcyOJVWnJ60zM1XWllNw - and check all of its playlists - there are playlist for each country, like:

- Top 100 Music Videos El Salvador
- Top 100 Songs Nicaragua
- Top 100 Music Videos Israel
- Top 100 Songs Hungary
- *and so on...*

Then, once you identify which are the playlists you need, copy their `playlist_id` and use them for make calls using the **[playlistitems](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list)** endpoint.