# Is there any way to access data on music within a video?

Tags: youtube-api

I have an idea for an app that would take a YouTube link and determine the music within the video. I noticed that below some videos with music, you can see the track title and artist in the description.

Can I access that info in any way with the API?

Answer (score 0):

To see the track, this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29667227/searching-only-for-music-tracks-on-youtube-with-the-youtube-api) can best answer that.

> The best you can do is to add a videoCategoryId parameter in your
>   query to the YouTube Data API. This ensures that only videos belonging
>   to this category are returned.

And for the artist, I think there is no other way as this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40858912/how-can-i-get-top-artist-youtube-data-api-v3) suggested.

> No, it's not possible to get the artist list via youtube data api.
>   Because the acceptable "type" values for search.list() does not have
>   artist resource:

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list):

> Acceptable values are: channel, playlist, video

Answer (score 0):

As written in previous answer, there is no data identifying artist and song title for the video.
You could get video description and parse it.
This is scraping and no guarantees that you will have structure there, however, usually uploaders have some standard way of posting description, e.g., from [this response's](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=SswR0aQbelQ&fields=items/snippet/title,items/snippet/description&key=AIzaSyAuS2XhULrVZFHTWkmMm_CD5Ip-fm52ZA0) description you could get `Slam Van by Stefan Kartenberg (c)`.